# --comments option not working for mysqldump, mariadb-dump on SUSE Linux - 10.5.13-MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a database running on a SUSE and `MariaDB 10.5.13.` No matter what I do, MariaDB always strips the comments from my stored procedures. Note that this does work correctly on my Windows 10 server with `MariaDB 10.4.24.`

Here is the sproc definition:

```
delimiter $$$
create procedure commentTest()
 begin
  # comment 1
  /* comment 2 */
  -- comment 3
  select 'comment test' message;
 end$$$
```

I have tried all of the following to no avail:

```
mysqldump -usomeUser -psomePassword --routines  test > ./test.sql
mysqldump -usomeUser -psomePassword --comments --routines  test > ./test.sql

mariadb-dump -usomeUser -psomePassword --routines  test > ./test.sql
mariadb-dump -usomeUser -psomePassword --routines --comments  test > ./test.sql
mariadb-dump -usomeUser -psomePassword -i --routines test > ./test.sql
mariadb-dump -usomeUser -psomePassword -i --routines --comments  test > ./test.sql
mariadb-dump -usomeUser -psomePassword --routines --comments=true  test > ./test.sql
```

The output is the same for all of these:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`odie`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `commentTest`()
begin



 select 'comment test' message;
end ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note that mariadb-dump is not available on my Windows version**, but the first two both work fine on the Windows server.

It seems like correctly backing up the database would be kind of a core function but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong if it's me. I have read all the docs I can find on this...is there a system setting somewhere I'm missing? Any help resolving this or pointing me to a third party app that works correctly would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: what does `show create procedure commentTest` show? seems like you are focusing on the dump when the problem may be how you added the procedure in the first place

Comment: Ugh - good call. You are correct. I needed to use the --comments flag when invoking the *CLI* otherwise the comments are ignored when I create a procedure. Why the default is to strip stuff away from your source code baffles me - but I appreciate your help! If you want to submit that as the answer, I'll gladly mark it as accepted - thanks - Jon.